# How to change header size in css

Tags: html, css

I am racking my brains on this one but I can't seem to find a solution.

From a semantic point of view I want to use a h2 header - but from a visual pov I want it to look exactly like a h5 header.

However, css is behaving oddly in relation to this, and seems to be treating the header text as normal text for formatting. So `font-size:60%;` is coming across as 60% the size of *normal* text - which is absolutely tiny! I've tried messing around with other aspects (like height), but to no avail. All stylistic properties relating to the header seem to disappear once you apply css to the font...

Comment: It'd be awfully helpful is we could see a code sample... there are way too many factors that could be contributing to this issue to simply guess. Are you using any CSS normalization? What browsers are affected, or do they all look the same?

Comment: Can we have a jsfiddle please?

Comment: different browsers have different defaults for headers, so your best solution is to use a CSS normalizer and then style each header specifically however you want

Comment: @mori57 e.g. .smaller70{
font-size:70%;
height:70%;
} <h2 class="smaller70">

Comment: Using percentage in font-size will correlate to the body font settings. So if you're body is set to 16px, your h2 will be 60% of that. There are other rules that come into play as well, but you could use px as an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use px instead of percentage for example 
 `h2{font-size:14px;
     height:50px;}`

Answer (score 3):

if you are going to use % definitions for CSS rules 
Use the html tag fix for font rendering.

Next include the body tag which defines all the base font information for the document.

The rest should work as desired.

```
/*css*/

html {font-size: 100.01%;}
body {font:italic bold 16px/30px Georgia, serif;}
h2 {font-size: 60%; line-height:60%;}
```

​

```
<!--HMTL-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div>blah</div>
        <h2>header</h2>
        <div>blah<br>blah</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

see [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Abyssoft/p9A4V/)